# Convert the int from c# gethashcode() back to string?

Tags: c#, hashcode

A really simple question:

I am doing a simple thing. I have few `string` like:

```
 string A = "usd";
```

And I want to get the hashcode in C#:

```
 int audusdReqId = Convert.ToInt32("usd".GetHashCode());
```

Now how could I convert the 32-bit integer `audusdReqId` back to the `string` "usd"?

Comment: If you could, it would mean there would be only 2^32 = 4 294 967 296 different strings in .net, that's fortunately not the case (that would represent roughly the possible combinations of 4 ascii characters...)

Answer (score 17):

You cannot. A hash code does not contain all of the necessary information to convert it back to a string. More importantly, you should be careful what you use `GetHashCode` for. [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) explains what you should use it for. You can't even guarantee that `GetHashCode` will return the same thing in different environments. So you should *not* be using `GetHashCode` for any cryptographic purposes.

If you are trying to create a binary representation of a string, you can use

```
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(someString);
```

This will give you a `byte[]` for that particular string. You can use `GetString` on Encoding to convert it back to a string:

```
var originalString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

If you are trying to cryptographically secure the string, you can use a symmetric encryption algorithm like AES as [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Correct, it's not a two-way conversion.  You have to use something else like symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the [hashcode/hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is that it has to be one way and that it cannot be converted back to the original value.

There are good reasons as to why this is so. A common usage would be password storage in a database for example. You shouldn't know the original value(the plain text password) and that is why you would normally use a hashcode to encode it one way.

There are also other usages as storing values to hashsets etc.